# XSLT: Add namespaces to nodes from skeleton

Tags: ruby, xml, xslt, nokogiri

I have a XML document that currently lacks namespaces at the node level.  I would like to be able to copy the namespaces defined in a skeleton document.

I am processing the document using Nokogiri (Ruby) and would require XSLT 1.0 or any other viable approach.

Is this even possible?

**Document**

```
  <routing
  xmlns:rt="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing"
  xmlns:cisco-ospf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:cisco-ospf"
  xmlns:ospf-devs="http://cisco.com/ns/ietf-ospf/devs"
  xmlns:ospf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"
  xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">
  <routing-instance>
      <name>default</name>
      <description>default-vrf [read-only]</description>
      <routing-protocols>
          <routing-protocol>
              <type>ospf:ospfv2</type>
              <name>100</name>
              <ospf>
                  <instance>
                      <af>rt:ipv4</af>
                      <router-id>6.6.6.6</router-id>
                      <admin-distance>
                          <intra-area>100</intra-area>
                          <inter-area>200</inter-area>
                          <external>10</external>
                      </admin-distance>
                      <auto-cost>
                          <enable>true</enable>
                          <reference-bandwidth>5000</reference-bandwidth>
                      </auto-cost>
                      <area>
                        <area-id>50</area-id>
                        <default-cost>50</default-cost>
                      </area>
                      <area>
                        <area-id>100</area-id>
                        <default-cost>100</default-cost>
                      </area>
                      <area>
                        <area-id>300</area-id>
                        <virtual-link>
                          <router-id>8.8.8.8</router-id>
                          <hello-interval>80</hello-interval>
                        </virtual-link>
                      </area>
                      <area>
                        <area-id>666</area-id>
                        <default-cost>100</default-cost>
                      </area>
                      <redistribution>
                          <static>
                              <redist-option>
                                  <metric>99999</metric>
                                  <metric-type>1</metric-type>
                              </redist-option>
                          </static>
                      </redistribution>
                  </instance>
              </ospf>
          </routing-protocol>
      </routing-protocols>
  </routing-instance>
```

**Skeleton**

```
  <routing
  xmlns:rt="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing"
  xmlns:cisco-ospf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:cisco-ospf"
  xmlns:ospf-devs="http://cisco.com/ns/ietf-ospf/devs"
  xmlns:ospf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"
  xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">
  <routing-instance xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">
    <name xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing"/>
    <router-id xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing"/>
    <description xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing"/>
      <interfaces xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">
        <interface xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing"/>
      </interfaces>
      <routing-protocols xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">
          <routing-protocol xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">
            <name xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing"/>
            <static-routes xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing"/>
              <ospf xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf">
                  <instance xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf">
                    <af xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"/>
                    <router-id xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"/>
                      <admin-distance xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf">
                        <intra-area xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"/>
                        <inter-area xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"/>
                        <external xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"/>
                      </admin-distance>
                      <nsr xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf">
                        <enable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"/>
                      </nsr>
                      <auto-cost xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf">
                        <enable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"/>
                        <reference-bandwidth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"/>
                      </auto-cost>
                      <area xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf">
                        <area-id xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"/>
                        <default-cost xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"/>
                      </area>
                      <default-metric xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:cisco-ospf"/>
                      <redistribution xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:cisco-ospf">
                          <static xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:cisco-ospf">
                              <redist-option xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:cisco-ospf">
                                <metric xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:cisco-ospf"/>
                                <metric-type xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:cisco-ospf"/>
                              </redist-option>
                          </static>
                      </redistribution>
                  </instance>
              </ospf>
          </routing-protocol>
      </routing-protocols>
  </routing-instance>
```

**Desired output**

```
  <routing
  xmlns:rt="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing"
  xmlns:cisco-ospf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:cisco-ospf"
  xmlns:ospf-devs="http://cisco.com/ns/ietf-ospf/devs"
  xmlns:ospf="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf"
  xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">
  <routing-instance xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-routing">
      <name>default</name>
      <description>default-vrf [read-only]</description>
      <routing-protocols>
          <routing-protocol>
              <type>ospf:ospfv2</type>
              <name>100</name>
              <ospf xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:ietf-ospf">
                  <instance>
                      <af>rt:ipv4</af>
                      <router-id>6.6.6.6</router-id>
                      <admin-distance>
                          <intra-area>100</intra-area>
                          <inter-area>200</inter-area>
                          <external>10</external>
                      </admin-distance>
                      <auto-cost>
                          <enable>true</enable>
                          <reference-bandwidth>5000</reference-bandwidth>
                      </auto-cost>
                      <area>
                        <area-id>50</area-id>
                        <default-cost>50</default-cost>
                      </area>
                      <area>
                        <area-id>100</area-id>
                        <default-cost>100</default-cost>
                      </area>
                      <area>
                        <area-id>300</area-id>
                        <virtual-link>
                          <router-id>8.8.8.8</router-id>
                          <hello-interval>80</hello-interval>
                        </virtual-link>
                      </area>
                      <area>
                        <area-id>666</area-id>
                        <default-cost>100</default-cost>
                      </area>
                      <redistribution xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:cisco-ospf">
                          <static>
                              <redist-option>
                                  <metric>99999</metric>
                                  <metric-type>1</metric-type>
                              </redist-option>
                          </static>
                      </redistribution>
                  </instance>
              </ospf>
          </routing-protocol>
      </routing-protocols>
  </routing-instance>
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of this repetition? A default namespace is inherited.

Comment: The namespaces can change throughout the document.  In this particular example there are two namespaces being utilized, but in larger documents it may be several.

Comment: I am afraid this is rather confusing. First, it's not necessary to repeat the namespace declaration as shown in your output. You only need it on the root `routing` element and on the `ospf` element. The other puzzle is the role of the Skeleton document. Are you hoping to have your stylesheet read this and adjust the output accordingly? That would be quite a challenge to implement in XSLT 1.0. Are you sure you need this? Namespaces are normally dictated by the schema - and schemas do not normally change so wildly.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired document contains many redundant namespace declarations.

There is no way to force an XSLT serializer to output redundant namespace declarations.

That's because it's hard to see any good reason why anyone would want them.

If your real aim is to change the namespaces of the elements according to some mapping file definition, rather than to output redundant namespace declarations representing those namespaces, then it would be best to change the example.